# DOMException error - Javascript play() can only be initiated by a user gesture, but I am calling it from touchStart

Tags: javascript, android, audio, domexception

In Javascript, I am getting a DOMException error, only on Android, when starting an audio clip using play() from a function that gets called with the touchstart event.

I set up the event with this code:

```
instructionsDiv.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
```

And I call the audio clip in the function with this code:

```
instructionsDiv.removeEventListener("touchstart", touchStart);
audio = new Audio(sndSources.welcome);
audio.play();
```

I get this warning:
"Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture."

And this error:
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture."

Here's my confusion:
1. I AM initiating it with a user gesture, using a touch event
2. this only happens on Android. it works fine on iPhone

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem. From my testings, Android doesn't consider "touchstart" as a gesture for media playback. I used "mousedown" instead and it works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately `mousedown` event isn't fired by Chrome Mobile

Answer (score 1):

I handle the same problem by using [HammerJs](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for the user gesture and bypass the DOM exception.

```
const mc = new Hammer(element);
mc.on('tap', function() {});
```